# где посмотреть используемые параметры apache по умолчанию?

Tags: apache, centos, веб-сервер

Использую Centos 7.1 
Установлен апач и php

Хочется настроить все параметры апача, такие как:

```
StartServers          3
MinSpareServers       3
MaxSpareServers       9
ServerLimit         256
MaxClients           12
```

Однако перед этим хотелось бы где-то узнать какие параметры использует апач сейчас?

В файле настроек /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf сейчас этих параметров нет.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html

Comment: И кстати это не дает ответа на мой вопрос - в выводе получается просто информация о том, что это такое и все.

Значений по умолчанию он не выводит.

Это просто результат разбора конфигурационного файла. Если там нет указанных значений - он не выводит их. Так что это не ответ на вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> где-то узнать какие параметры использует апач сейчас

если в конфигурацию внесены изменения (неизвестно какие), а процессы *apache* после этого не перезапускались, то узнать, какими значениями пользуются эти процессы в настоящий момент, насколько я понимаю — невозможно.

---

узнать, какие значения параметров будут актуальны **после** перезапуска, можно с помощью модуля [`mod_info`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html). после его включения (и перезапуска процессов *apache*) по адресу `http://localhost/server-info` (он указан в конфигурации этого модуля) можно получить такую, например, информацию (по упомянутым вами параметрам):

```
Module Name: prefork.c
...
    MaxClients - Deprecated name of MaxRequestWorkers
...
Current Configuration:
    In file: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf
       9: StartServers 5
      10: MinSpareServers 5
      11: MaxSpareServers 10
      12: MaxRequestWorkers 150
```

---

по поводу встроенных умолчаний для упомянутых параметров (т.е., если параметр не определён в актуальной конфигурации) следует смотреть документацию к используемой версии программы *apache* (ссылки и цитаты ниже приведены для версии 2.4, конкретно для семейства модулей mpm):

- [`StartServers`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#startservers):

  > The default value differs from MPM to MPM. worker and event default to StartServers 3; prefork defaults to 5; mpmt_os2 defaults to 2.
- [`MinSpareServers`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html#minspareservers):

  > Default:  MinSpareServers 5
- [`MaxSpareServers`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html#maxspareservers):

  > Default:  MaxSpareServers 10
- [`ServerLimit`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#serverlimit):

  > prefork 256 (default)
  > worker 16 (default)
  > event 16 (default)
- [`MaxRequestWorkers`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) (старое имя — `MaxClients`):

  > For non-threaded servers (i.e., prefork), MaxRequestWorkers translates into the maximum number of child processes that will be launched to serve requests. The default value is 256; to increase it, you must also raise ServerLimit.
  > For threaded and hybrid servers (e.g. event or worker) MaxRequestWorkers restricts the total number of threads that will be available to serve clients. For hybrid MPMs the default value is 16 (ServerLimit) multiplied by the value of 25 (ThreadsPerChild). Therefore, to increase MaxRequestWorkers to a value that requires more than 16 processes, you must also raise ServerLimit.

Comment: Плюсусь. И ещё хорошая практика в /etc/httpd/conf.d/ кидать tuning.conf чтобы легко можно было менять параметры.